# Using INSERT INTO with two values, WHERE clause for only one

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert two values from two separate tables and filter one of the values with a WHERE clause.
Currently I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO Combined_List (Email, Product)
SELECT meta_value, item_name FROM user_list, order_items 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%user_email%'
```

The `meta_value` contains various information so I'm trying to filter just the entries that have anything like `user_email` as their `meta_key`.
The problem is that when I run this the entries are repeated hundreds of extra times.
Am I using the correct syntax to filter just the `meta-key` and not the `item_name`?

Comment: What did you want to see in the table? A list of each email against a product they ordered? You need to join the tables some how if so, but we would need to see the table structures.

Comment: You are using misleading terminology.  "Sorting" generally refers to presenting data in a certain order.  The term you want is "filtering".

Comment: Ideally I would like the product ordered and the user email lined up in a new table.  The existing tables both have an ID in common, but I'm unsure how to create a new table out of a join.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the user_list and order_items on their common field!
Right now you are combining every entry from user_list with every entry from order_items.

Comment: Once we get your reputation up to 50, you'll be able to write stuff like this as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Combined_List (Email, Product)
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value, item_name FROM user_list, order_items 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%user_email%'
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO Combined_List (Email, Product)
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value, item_name FROM user_list
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%user_email%'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value, item_name FROM order_items 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%user_email%'
```

EDIT:

Not knowing your structure, this is the best I can do

```
INSERT INTO Combined_List (Email, Product)
SELECT a.meta_value, b.item_name
FROM user_list a
JOIN order_items b ON a.meta_key = b.meta_key
where a.meta_key LIKE '%user_email%'
```

Use a PK - FK relationship instead of `a.meta_key = b.meta_key`

Comment: I tried this and the emails are still repeating, the products are not though.

Comment: Neither query solves the problem.  The first still has a full outer join because no joining fields are specified.  The second assumes both tables have the same fields, which is unlikely.